# adding GNU GPL for a java application

Tags: java

I am not getting where i have to put the licence file of the third party libraries while making jar through eclipse can any one please help me in this issue. While making a jar from eclipse i am getting the following warning

> The operation repacks referenced libraries.
>
> Please review the licences associated with libraries you wish to
>   reference to make sure you are able to repack them using this
>   application. Note also that this operation does not copy signature
>   from files from original libraries to the generated jar file

Can any one please let me know this type of error messages will lead to any problem using jar file that generate through eclipse

Thanks in advance

Comment: Legal questions about software licenses are off-topic on Stack Overflow, but *may* be on-topic on its [Programmers sister site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Please see [stackoverflow.com/tags/licensing/info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/licensing/info).

Answer (score 2):

The GNU organization has a [how-to](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html) for setting up your use of its' license

Comment: Can you please let me know if any warnings or errors that we found during a building a jar means warning like above will cause any damage to the jar developed